# What is common practice when adding a new item, Dialog or Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog

I am trying to build a simple list interface for a set of items.

When adding a new item, the user needs to fill in multiple details for the item, pick from drop down menus, enter figures ect before it is then saved to the list.

what is the recommended way to present this entry view? is it to start a new activity , or make a dialogue box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This highly depends on the amount of information the user needs to fill in. I've done both, and they can both be the correct way of doing it.

If it's only 1-3 fields and nothing major, i'd say use a dialog. If it's anything above that, or contains date/time pickers, i'd say use a new activity. (Reason for date/time pickers is that it's a bit weird for a dialog to open a new dialog on top of itself).

So in your case, i'd say go for an activity.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I figured i was hitting the middle ground between them (and a bit to new to android to pick which to learn first.) Much appreciated